# Why is asking for disused words unacceptable?

Tags: discussion

I was wondering, why is it unacceptable to ask for word-recommendations involving disused or ancient words?

Comment: Is it unacceptable? Or do questions have to be couched carefully?

Comment: @AndrewLeach It seems they're unacceptable, based on my experience.

Comment: Well, you could link to evidence. But a good question explaining what is required **and why** and what research has already been done [yada, yada, you know the drill] may well be acceptable.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I believe he’s talking about [this one](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/102826/2085).

Comment: Oh. Right. It appears no-one actually understood what was required; and there wasn't much explanation of *why* either. :-(

Comment: @Andrew: I think it was quite clear from the protracted exchange of comments that OP wanted a "word" that *isn't currently used, and therefore has no particular meaning*, so he could assign to it his own special meaning. It may have taken a while to establish that, but once we got there it seemed (and still seems) totally Off Topic/Not Constructive to me.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The question is simple enough and clear enough to understand -- it doesn't matter what that word was going to be used *for*. And for the record, of course the *meaning* of the word is relevant, otherwise any random configuration of letters would be acceptable. It was my understanding that it was asking for archaic words that was the issue.

Comment: @Django: I don't want to rake over the coals indefinitely, but in your comments you did say you wanted to *avoid any discussions of semantics*, and *it's important the word lacks connotations*. Which I can only interpret as meaning you wanted us to supply you with a "word" that's not only not used, but is actually ***unknown***, so your readers won't be in a position to argue with you when you use it to mean something other than what it originally meant.

Answer (score 5):

Stack Exchange staff have said many times that single word requests should be discouraged. Some moderators have taken that to heart. However it's not an absolute ban. There are exceptions: a single word request which is especially interesting to English experts, when the question is clear and well researched, would certainly be on topic here.

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/102826/whats-a-good-unfamiliar-word-for-accomplishment